# Download file from GCP instance workplace to local computer

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I have a zip file in my GCP instance workplace (working on VSCode). I wanted to download this file in my local Linux Mint machine. I ran the following command:

```
gcloud compute scp username@instance_name:/project_dir/models.zip /home/soumik/Downloads --zone asia-northeast1-a
```

When I run this command, it shows the progress of download:

```
100%   13GB  59.8MB/s   03:46
```

But I don't see any file named `models.zip` in this `/home/soumik/Downloads` local directory.
What can be the probable reason for this?

I have also run the following command for authentication:

```
gcloud auth login
```

and authenticated the url. But still it didn't work, means I don't see any models.zip file in my local machine directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the download completing or is there an error? Is the downloaded file hidden? Use `ls -la /home/soumik/Downloads`. Do you have enough disk space? Try enabling debugging with `--scp-flag=-v`.

Comment: Download gets completed. No errors. I have checked the hidden files. I have enough disk space. But I see no files named models.zip.

Comment: Now, I have decided moving the file to Storage Bucket first, then download it from there.

Comment: Any results with the bucket ? What was the result of `--scp-flag=-v` flag ? Can you post full output ?